# Get default scroll direction for UIScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have an application that uses more `UIScrollViews` and `extensions` from it like `UICollectionViews` and `UITableViews` and for a little dynamism I have created some general functions to help me with some paddings / margins.

My functions are created as `extensions` for `UIScrollView` and I want to use them just when the scroll view is `only vertical`.

**My Question**

How can I find the scrolling direction of a UIScrollView?

I have found a lot of answers of how to find the scrolling direction, but I need when the `UIScrollView` is initialised to find the scrolling direction of it, if it's `vertical or horizontal`.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can compare the content size with the frame size. Whichever axis is exceeding the frame size will be scrolling.

Comment: @Desdenova i thought about that, but it's possible that a collection view have just one cell which is smaller or as much as the width of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I can think of in order to get the scroll direction before scrolling is to react accordingly to the type of UIScrollView in question.

So first step check if it is a UIScrollView, UICollectionView or UITableView.

**In the case of a UITableView**

I think a fair assumption here is that the scrolling direction will be vertical

**In the case of a UIScrollView**

This one could be tricky but I guess here you would have to compare the content size of the scroll view with the frame of the scrollview as Desdenova suggested and this can suggest if you can scroll horizontally and / or vertically.

**In the case of a UICollectionView**

This data will lie in the in the layout of the UICollectionView.

For example, I set up a basic UICollectionView in Storyboard using a FlowLayout without any data in it.

[image: UICollectionView UICollectionViewFlowLayout scroll direction]

Then I add this code somewhere appropriate

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    if layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal {
        print("horizontal")
    }
    else {
        print("vertical")
    }
}
```

This prints out `horizontal`.

Comment: exactly this code for `UICollectionView` worked and i chose it
FTM, I am glad it works with `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

For the UIScrollView you have to use the UIScrollViewDelegate `scrollViewDidScroll`  which is helps you in UIScrollView's Scroll direction also for that you have to add some checks for the get the directions:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    // Update ScrollView direction
    if self.lastContentOffset.y > scrollView.contentOffset.y && self.lastContentOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
            // Vertical Scroll
    } else {
            // Horizontal Scroll
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working, but it's not quite what I have been looking for. I was curious if there is some method to get the scroll view (i found for collection view) scroll direction when it's initialized, not just when you scroll